# Invert svg from right to left

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to invert svg but I'm not understanding how to do that.
Currently it appear from right to left, I've to do the same thing but from left to right
Someone could please explain it?
Here is the code:

```html
 <svg class="separator__svg" width="100%" height="400" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" fill="#fff" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M 100 100 V 10 L 0 100" />
                <path d="M 30 73 L 100 18 V 10 Z" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#01f7b6" stroke-width="0" />
            </svg>
```

Thanks
PP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `transform` attribute with value `scale(-1 1)`.

```html
<svg class="separator__svg" width="100%" height="400" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" fill="#fff" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <path d="M 100 100 V 10 L 0 100" />
     <path d="M 30 73 L 100 18 V 10 Z" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#01f7b6" stroke-width="0" />
</svg>

<hr/>
<svg class="separator__svg" width="100%" height="400" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" fill="#fff" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     transform="scale(-1 1)">
     <path d="M 100 100 V 10 L 0 100" />
     <path d="M 30 73 L 100 18 V 10 Z" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#01f7b6" stroke-width="0" />
</svg>
```